# ActiveX Ms Chart Control Not Rendered Under IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, activex, controls, mschart

We're using Visual C++ 6.0 to develop a web-application, which uses ActiveX controls. 
One of them is this Microsoft Chart Control(6.0), to show some statistics or something.

Well, it works and shows up fine when the .ocx is run under a PC that has Internet Explorer 6.0.

But under an IE 7 machine, that chart isn't displayed; there is a blank image instead. It doesn't show up. No errors or exceptions thrown.

When I run the application from Eclipse in hosted mode though, it works fine again. Only when opened in IE 7, that chart disappears.

This MS Chart Control apparently uses MSCHART20.ocx

Thanks in advance for any advice towards a fix, or a workaround, or a needed upgrade.

I don't like upgrades though. But I need to figure out what kind of upgrade can be done to make this work.

Comment: Do you have a public repro page that demonstrates the problem? Are you sure the OCX control is installed on the IE7 PC?

Comment: I couldn't find any yet. There are many issues about ActiveX permissions and kill bits etc., but this is not one of them. I don't think we have any problem with IE blocking ActiveX controls.

Comment: On IE7, have you tried pressing CTRL-A. That sounds odd but I am searching for a solution where the OCX doesn't render in some cases unless I press CTRL-A!